# Make variables created in preprocess_page hook available to content type templates

Tags: theming, 8, blocks

I'm attempting to render a block plugin programmatically in a content type template. I understand how to render the block programmatically in a page template. like so

mytheme.theme

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables){
    $myblock = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')->createInstance('myblockid',[]);
    $variables['myblock'] = $myblock->build();
```

page.html.twig

```
<div class="my block">
{{ myblock }}
</div>
```

However in

node--contenttype.html.twig

```
<div class="my block">
{{ myblock }}
</div>
```

Produces nothing. Is there another hook I should be using? Or is there a better way to do this entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by placing the code into the preprocess node hook instead of the preprocess page. Like so

mytheme.theme

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables){
    $myblock = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')->createInstance('myblockid',[]);
    $variables['myblock'] = $myblock->build();
```

Comment: Correct. Variables are not shared between those functions.